# Three.js bounding box wrong alignment

Tags: three.js, bounding-box, particle-system

In my program, I add points to a particle system and then calculate bounding box for it as:

```
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(0xff0000));
var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( object, 0xffff00 );
scene.add(box);
```

geometry is instance of BufferGeometry and it contains all the points constituting particle system.

What I see is that bounding box is wrongly aligned. Its in direction perpendicular to expected direction.

[image]

So I expect wireframe structure to envelop the point cloud.

Do I need to do something extra here?

Edit:

Code I am working upon is in github repo:
[github file](https://github.com/verma/plasio/blob/master/js/render.js)

In function ParticleSystemBatcher.prototype.push, points read from a file are pushed in particle system.I have added code above at end of this function. Bounding box does appear,but aligned wrongly.

Comment: The points rendered may not be the same as the points in memory, the shader might be doing additional transformations. Not enough code to tell whats going on.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Wow, that was quite an incredible amount of code. Somewhere one third down i see an instance of `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with a vertex shader containing some logic. If this is used then it makes sense that this is misaligned.

Comment: But shader stuff is not in that method I mentioned. So would it still impact the bounding box alignment?Pardon me for basic questions. I am very new to both Js and three.js.

Comment: I can't look at all the code, you'd have to make an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, but i can say with 99% degree certainty that this is what is going on. Try debugging the way i suggest in the answer.

Comment: And i think you are wrong. Upon looking at the code, the shader stuff is referenced in the method by `this.material` (line 1844). Please accept the answer. In your case you need to apply the logic from line `462` on the cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` which applies some logic to positioning these vertices. Hence, the result rendered is different than the result stored in the main memory.

You can debug this by making a `Mesh`  or sprite, and positioning each where you expect the particle in the system to be using just rhe scene graph (`object.position.set()`). The result will be a bunch of dots that are not in the same space as your particle system. These will also fit the bounding box.

The solution is to apply the same transformation that is being applied by the shader.